# Task.cancel(false) or Task.cancel(true)

Tags: java, threadpool

I'm working on a little system of taxes for some kingdoms in game. So I have a function such as "Kingdom ruler can reset tax rate's an interval for it's gaining".

**Image of console log**

[image]

To avoid data replacement when the task is completed with new data. We just reset old model by new. And next schsedule will invoke by new

```
public synchronized void startSystem(float rate, int interval) {
    rate = rate < 0
            ? ETaxState.GOOD.getValue() : rate > ETaxState.INSANE.getValue()
            ? ETaxState.INSANE.getValue() : rate;

    interval = interval < 1
            ? MIN_INTERVAL : interval > MAX_INTERVAL
            ? MAX_INTERVAL : interval;

    taxModel = new TaxesModel(rate, interval);
    task = ThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 1_000, interval * 3_600_600);
}
```

This method stop the current task and reset the model for a future task with new tax rates and interval of income get.

```
public synchronized void stopSystem() {
    if (task != null) {
        task.cancel(false);
        task = null;
    }

    taxModel = null;
}
```

Finally I have a some instance for invoke this methods. Firstly we stop the current task, and after get thecorrect numbers we set a new task -> launch.

```
try {
    myKingdom.getTaxes().stopSystem();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(command);
    st.nextToken(); //go throught command

    float newTaxRate = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    int newInterval = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

    myKingdom.getTaxes().startSystem(newTaxRate, newInterval);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    log.error("Can't change task", e);
}
```

Im afraid the `task.cancel(false)` becuase javadoc says, that task will be done and after will be canceled. If I set the true value inside cancel, I get the immediently interrupt of task, but I do not know what it will lead to... And how to be?

In final game example it must looks like that:
When player reset the new values of task, the CURRENT task must completed with old tax rates, or I get the bugs...

Thank you for help!
Sorry for my bad english!